# Put a with a:hover over hyperlinked image?

Tags: html, css, image

On the mobile version of my responsive site, I get this problem:

[image]

The image is above the navigation, how do I fix this with positioning without moving the image. This is the [website](http://www.bossfakeid.co.uk/index.html) - Resize the window until you see the nav turn into a toggle.

I'VE FIXED THE PROBLEM.

Comment: Its as simple as that->just move your html according to how you want it to display + tinker your css a bit... EDIT: Ok I am posting the answer below.

Comment: Well that's helpful.. I could answer almost every question on here with that..

Comment: I don't get your point exactly,do you mean the logo is above the navigation toggle button?

Comment: Try click on the bottom two links in the nav bar when it's on the mobile version and you'll see that it just hits the logo instead of the nav links.

Comment: Your problem is the image size. Why have you made the image so large when you only need to show the text in it. In this case, at least, the only solution is to crop your image.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully my answer will work.

I would suggest you not to research your code. I am seeing the problem in logo.

I found your logo canvas bigger than the logo just like if you open the logo file in Adobe Photoshop, your logo is looking just like.

```
__________________________
|                        |
|                        |
|        L O G O         |
|                        |
|________________________|
```

Actually this empty area is overlapping other html objects like last two nav links.

*So here is the problem that when mouse goes over last two links, it actually finds transparent canvas of image above the navigation. So mouse takes it as it is over an image rather than the nav links.*

```
__________________________
| Vendor                 |
| Contact                |
|        L O G O         |
|                        |
|________________________|
```

So trim the logo image along the bonding box (most outer edges) of logo to remove surrounding margins in photoshop or any other your favourite image editing tool.

And rather than having empty canvas in image, use margin/padding while working with web development.

Hope this will help you. If you need further assistance, you will find me right here for your help.